# NetLogo: how to read an adjacency matrix and create corresponding graph?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I have an adjacency matrix like

```
        [0 1]
        [1 0]
```

it will output a line connect with two node
but as the matrix become larger and larger there will have many combination like

```
        [0 1 1]          [0 1 0]
        [1 0 0]    or    [1 0 1]
        [1 0 0]          [0 1 0]
```

How to read such a matrix and use it to create turtles and links for the graph described by the matrix?

Comment: FYI, the kind of matrix you're asking about is called an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). As originally written your question wasn't very clear, but I think I understand what you want, so I made some edits to improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

The [NW extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension) has a [nw:load-matrix](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#load-matrix) primitive that handles this for you.

Note that (as of February 2014) the extension isn't bundled with NetLogo; you'll need to download and install it.